# Trying to make a basic menu in HTML, one button is displayed, other doesn't work with same CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to improve my HTML as i'm a beginner. I've started trying to create a basic website and i'm working on the menu, I made a button "home" (not actually a working button but it is visually) and I tried making another button next to it with the same CSS. I used different classes but they both had the same CSS code, why isn't the class applying to the second button and only the first ?

HTML Code snippet:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="HOME_menuButton">
        <p id="menuItem">Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="LEWIS_menuButton">
        <p id="menuItem">Lewis</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    background-color: #6699ff;
    width: 845px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 305px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.HOME_menuButton {
    background-color: #ccb3ff;
    width: 160px;
    height: 78px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#menuItem {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: Bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.LEWIS_menuButton {
    background-color: #ccb3ff;
    width: 160px;
    height: 78px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: ids are unique; if you have two elements with the same id, like here (`menuItem`), stuff will break.

Comment: The reason is that id's are unique. You need to use a class. You said you tried using a class but did not include that in your question. I almost posted an answer but hesitated in light of your question being unclear on what you said; what you tried but did not post.

Answer (score 1):

An ID in HTML/CSS code is meant to be unique. You can only use it once if you want to write correct code.

I suspect, that your browser doesn't like to usage of the duplicate ID `#menuItem` (which should be a class instead). Try to convert `#menuItem` into a class.